# microsoft teams microphone not working

Tags: linux, arch-linux, microsoft-teams

i am using arch Linux.

my mic runs perfectly well on all my apps ( zoom, ...)

but it doesn't seem to be working using Microsoft teams.

either the web app(login using Firefox , chrome) or even when installing teams from the AUR.

i also didn't found lots of people having the same issue on the arch wiki so i'm posting here for further help.

i really appreciate it if someone helps me with that, i'm new to arch.

i am using lenovo ideapad 330 .

i have installed teams from the aur repo   `https://aur.archlinux.org/teams.git`

there is no errors while running from the terminal the command is : `teams`  it opens normally.

in the device settings in teams the built in audio and mic are selected.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some details. What is your hardware? What version of teams? How did you install it? Are there any error messages shown if you run from  the terminal? Have you tried looking at the settings to see if you have more than one option for microphone? I have used Teams on my Arch and it worked fine, so this is something with your system.

Comment: i have edited my question thankyou @terdon

Comment: Did you try selecting a different mic in the options? There should be more than one available.

Comment: no there is only one  ( built-in analogue stereo)